# Classic ASP File Sharing Concern

Tags: asp-classic, file-sharing

Whenever I disable file sharing (via Folder Properties\Sharing\Share) or remove Everyone from the list, I no longer able to browse the website via Internet Explorer.

Is this a requirement for classic ASP?
Our website is deployed in intranet, we don't want the user to able to browse the directory via Windows Explorer (e.g. \server-name\path).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope, this isn't a requirement to run ASP pages. However, you do need to add some specific users to your folder permissions if you don't wish to use EVERYONE. if you're not using windows authentication, you simply need to add the account that runs the site through IIS / AppPool settings. This account is usually named like IUSR_. You'll also need to add the NETWORK SERVICES account to your permissions. After adding them, simply restart IIS and you should be good to go.

Comment: FYI, I added iis_iusrs and Networkservice accounts/removed Everyone.
User is asked to prompted to authenticate -- they user account no longer works. (the site is using Windows Authentication).

Comment: that suggestion was if you were NOT using windows authentication (as stated in my answer). if you are using W.A., simply create a user group, put all of the users in that group, then add that group to the permissions.